# Text is shifted when mixing floated and relatively positioned elements

Tags: css, html

I'm looking to solve with CSS a problem that I found far trickier than expected.

Here is the smallest (valid) html fragment I was able to build that expose the issue:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            body, div {margin: 0; color: white;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="float: left; background-color: #000; width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
        <div style="background-color: #333; position: relative; left: 200px; height: 200px;">This is a test !</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does someone know how to prevent the text "This is a test !" To be shifted to the right by the floated element ?

I'm guessing that the floated element is the culprit since when I remove it the text is at the right place. Also changing the order of the divs doesn't yield the expected result.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `left: 200px;` on your right side div with `margin-left: 200px;`

[**Fiddle to prove here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/eyKhq/)

Comment: Geez, I feel so dumb right now... I'm looking to achieve what you just did (in 5min, including the time for you to come across my question) for over 2 hours... Thank you !

Comment: Hehe no problem. I've had the same thing happen to me many times ;)